# Calculate when growth exceeds for based on given rates

Tags: linear-algebra

Company A has two products, product A and product B.

- Product A was introduced in 2015, and total units sold are $100~000$. It is growing at $8~\%$ YoY.
- Product B was introduced in 2018, and total units sold are $35~000$. It is growing at $14~\%$ YoY.

I'd like to calculate the when (day or month) in future, when sales of Product B will exceed Product A.

What would the equation look like for this? How would to solve for when Product B units > Product A units sold.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: The equations will be made like this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compound_interest

Comment: I would start by making a timeline so that $t=0$ corresponds to the beginning of the year 2015, and $t=1$ corresponds to the beginning of the year $2016$, etc (by the way, do we assume that the products were introduced in the beginning of the year? There's a possibility of almost 12 month's worth of error in the numerics otherwise ...). Now we can set
$$
A(t=0) = 100~000
$$
Do you know how to calculate $A(t=1)$ ?

Comment: Yes. we can assume they're introduced in Jan 01.

Comment: A(t = 1) = 100k + (8% * 100k), where t = 2016. 8% AGR.

Comment: Okay, very good. Now, can you calculate the value of $A(t)$ for an arbitrary value of $t$?

Comment: It's 8% YoY. So, compounded growth. A(t = 2) = 8% of (8% of (100k + (8% * 100k))) ? That's the equation I am looking for.